# Chart.js não é exibido no Android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, apache-cordova

App desenvolvido em Ionic.

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.9.3
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Linux 4.10
```

Chart.js não é exibido no emulador do android. `ionic cordova run android --emulator`.

[image]

> Obs.: Android 6 (api 23) funciona, Android 7 (api 25) e 8 (api 26) não
>   funciona.

Mas no web view (`ionic cordova run browser`) e iPhone (Ionic View App) ele é exibido perfeitamente.

[image]

html template

`<canvas #elChart></canvas>`

scss

```
canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

component.ts (Eu tentei setar responsive e maintainAspectRatio como true ou false)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.elChart.nativeElement, {
      type: this.typeChart,
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: this.dataChart,
          backgroundColor: this.colorsChart,
          borderWidth: 0
        }],
        labels: this.labelsChart
      },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
      }

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvi temporariamente com a [issue #4570 Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4570) mas espero que me ajudem a resolver o problema completamente, fazendo o Chart.js funcionar normalmente.

Solução alternativa - exibe o gráfico, mas as ações serão perdidas (clique do mouse, passar o mouse sobre etc):

1- Envolva seu **canvas** dentro de um **div** (adicione os estilos que você pode precisar à div)

```
<div><canvas height="400" id="myChart" width="400"></canvas></div>
```

2- Remova qualquer "animação" (embora você possa alterar o código do item 3 / para usar o evento endAnimation para rastrear quando realizar a correção temporal) - Adicione essas opções:

```
options: { animation:{duration:0}, ..... }
```

3- Adicione o seguinte código (simples mas pode ser melhorado para o final de animação se necessário):

(jQuery)

```
$('#myChart').parent().html('<img style="max-height:100%;height:auto;width:100%;max-width:100%;margin:auto;display:inline;" src="' + chart.toBase64Image() + '" />');
```

(javascript)

```
document.getElementById('myChart').parentElement.innerHTML = '<img style="max-height:100%;height:auto;width:100%;max-width:100%;margin:auto;display:inline;" src="' + chart.toBase64Image() + '" />';
```

Siga a [issue #5184 Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5184) no Github